# Form validation library for Android?

Tags: java, android, validation

Is there any mature form validation API / library for Android?
I've found http://code.google.com/p/android-binding/ but it seems that is under heavy development.

**UPDATE:** Just to clarify my question. Currently, I have hardcoded form validation imperatively. And I would like to know, if there is a mature form validation library that allows me to declaratively specify validators (e.g. directly in XML or in code using annotations or by functional fluent way, ...).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The library now supports annotations, you can validate your fields just by adding them. Here is an example code snippet.

```
@NotEmpty
@Order(1)
private EditText fieldEditText;

@Checked(message = "You must agree to the terms.")
@Order(2)
private CheckBox iAgreeCheckBox;

@Length(min = 3, message = "Enter atleast 3 characters.")
@Pattern(regex = "[A-Za-z]+", message = "Should contain only alphabets")
@Order(3)
private TextView regexTextView;

@Password
@Order(4)
private EditText passwordEditText;

@ConfirmPassword
@Order(5)
private EditText confirmPasswordEditText;
```

The order annotation is optional and specifies the order in which the fields should be validated. This is ONLY required if you want the order of the fields to be preserved during validation. There are also other annotations such as `@Email`, `@IpAddress`, `@Isbn`, etc.,

**Android Studio / Gradle**

```
compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.2'
```

Check for the latest available version.

**Eclipse**
You can download the jar from [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.mobsandgeeks%22%20AND%20a%3A%22android-saripaar%22) and add it to your Android `libs` directory.

**Old Answer (Saripaar v1)**
I have authored a library for validation. Here is the [associated blog](http://honeyicejelly.blogspot.in/2012/09/live-by-rules-baby-at-least-few.html) and the [project](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar). I have sucessfully used it in production applications and it currently satisfies most of the common scenarios that we face in validation forms for Android. There are rules that come out of the box and if you need to write your own, you can do that by writing your own Rule.

Here is a snippet that illustrates the use of the library.

```
validator.put(nameEditText, Rules.required("Name is required."));
validator.put(nameEditText, Rules.minLength("Name is too short.", 3));
validator.put(emailEditText, Rules.regex("Email id is invalid.", Rules.REGEX_EMAIL, trim));
validator.put(confirmPwdEditText, Rules.eq("Passwords don\'t match.", pwdEditText);
```

There are also `or` and `and` rules that allow you to perform `&&` and `||` operations on several rules. There is also a `compositeOr` and `compositeAnd` rule that allows you to perform validations between several Views.

If any of those seem to be insufficient, you can always write your own rule by extending the [Rule](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar/blob/master/src/com/mobsandgeeks/saripaar/Rule.java) class.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the information. Are there any stock ValidatorListeners that would e.g. highlight the error input boxes, etc.?

Comment: You will receive the failedView and failedRule in the onFailure callback. If you want to highlight the EditText fields, you can always call the setError() or the requestFocus() methods. The failed rule will have a failure message when you can get by calling the failedRule.getFailureMessage().

Comment: Are you planing any declarative extensions for that? (That can be just applied and you do not need to code it every time.)

Comment: Yes, I'm looking into annotations and XML declarations.

Comment: @TN. I have begun to add annotation support to my library. Check the project link for updates.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [OVal](http://oval.sourceforge.net/)

```
public class BusinessObject {

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Length(max=32)
private String name;

 ...
}

// collect the constraint violations
List<ConstraintViolation> violations = validator.validate(bo);
```

I'm planing to uses it in my next project since is has a variety of expression languages, but only Java is hard required.

It is not JSR303 compilant, but supports those annotations too.

Comment: Do you know any Android UI binding for that library?

Comment: I guess you have to bind it manually, but I think the Validator will work on any class like Form or Dialog, since you can annoatate any method you create or overwrite.

Comment: I looking for something which also helps with UI, but thank you for a hint +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to validate text fields(EditText) then i will suggest you to use Pattern and Matcher with regex expressions, ofcourse we are not using android API here but android support java API hence you can.

Comment: You suggest to create own validation library, but my question is there any already existing which is mature.

Answer (score 0):

Using either

```
android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.Validator;
myTextview.setValidator(myCustomValidator);
```

or `myTextView.setError(error-message)` 
in an `onTextChangedListener`
works fine and the second one looks really great.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the simple and mature way to validate the input texts or forms:

```
private EditText et_first_name;
et_first_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_first_name);
et_first_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_first_name);
first_name.matches("^(?i)(?=.{1,20}$)([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9-_.]*$)"); // use the regex expression inside brackets and returns the error status .
```

Comment: But this is not a declarative way of specifying validators. (Currently, I have hardcoded it like you suggest, but I am looking for a better way.)

Answer (score 0):

Use Oval library for validation in android
It is object based validation library used in Object classes

Answer (score 0):

since I fought with such problems on my own, I added this functionality to the core functions of my BARACUS application framework. See http://baracusframework.blogspot.de/2014/01/baracus-from-scratch-part-6-automatic.html for details.

The concept includes a declarative binding of named validators in the form plus the automatic routing of any constraint violation messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormValidateor Library - https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/8353.
It works with jetpack compose and view system.