# Android Form: how can I add form validation for empty fields?

Tags: android, forms, field

I'm new at Android development. I tried to copy codes from android SDK's **login form** but couldn't get any result. Can anyone help me, how can I give "this field is required" error to a text field?  Also some explanation would be great, I really do not understand anything from **login form** codes. There is no **android:onClick** or sth like that, how could the system understand that I have clicked on the sign in button? and much more questions I have... For more details see the images:

[image]
<sub>(source: [coredogs.com](http://coredogs.com/content_media/lessons/servercore/restricting-access/logging-in/log-in-empty-fields-errors.png))</sub>

Comment: You could have given links. I don't know what you call "login form"... Did you check the layout xml file, there should be an entry for android:onClick, it will point to a method that is called when user clicks.

Comment: @snicolas : try to create a new activity, there is a **login activity**. When you clicked on **sign in** button, if you didn't give a name or password, it says **this field is required**... I'm talking about that.

Comment: @snicolas [photo](http://coredogs.com/content_media/lessons/servercore/restricting-access/logging-in/log-in-empty-fields-errors.png)

Comment: You should check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613321/form-validation-library-for-android. All answers are very interesting.

Comment: Yes; well, actually it's a script which does the job: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4751173/glorfindel?tab=activity&sort=revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Layout file in which you can make your 2 EditText boxes. And then put the Button at the bottom and put validation on that button. like EditText cant be equal to " ".

put validation on EditText in Function like that.

```
public void bttoncall(View view) {

EditText usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
sUsername = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
if (sUsername.matches("")) {
// Show Toast
 Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 // Show Error on edittext
 usernameEditText.setError("Your message");
 return;
 }
```

And call that function from your button Onclick. So whenever that button will press, your function will call.

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Tap Me"
    android:onClick="buttoncall" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has an accepted error, but from your image EditText.setError() would probably be more appropriate -- rather than spamming the user with Toasts or only giving feedback on one field at a time.

Comment: I think this method is better than toast spam