# How to determine if any fields associated with an activity have had their errors set?

Tags: android, input, android-activity, validation

I am performing some input validation in an `onClickListener()`. While I'm okay with my validation methods I'm concerned about the way I am determining if any of the validated inputs have errors. For the time being I am setting a field `isValid` on the Activity to true at the the start of the `onClickListener()` and then in my validation methods setting it to false if validation is failed.

After validation is completed and before doing anything with the data I can check `isValid` to ensure all input is good. While the method works it feels brittle. Here's some code to illustrate:

```
private OnClickListener dcClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AuthenticationActivity.this.isValid = true; // set to true for this pass
        emailValidation();
        // more validation methods here...

        if (AuthenticationActivity.this.isValid) {
            Log.i(TAG, "everything valid!");
        }
    }
};

private void emailValidation() {
    if (!isValidEmail(emailInput.getText()
            .toString())) {
        emailInput.setError(getString(R.string.bad_email));

        AuthenticationActivity.this.isValid = false; // same in other methods
    }
}
```

The thought of creating a collection of inputs and then iterating through it to determine if any had errors also crossed my mind. Is there something built into the framework to handle activity level validation? Is there a better solution than what I have outlined here? Is there a commonly used pattern for this paradigm?

Comment: There is nothing built into the framework but there is a third party library that may meet your needs.  See the following question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613321/form-validation-library-for-android

Answer (score 0):

You could build a custom validation function that returns a boolean, and in a For each loop go through all the view calling that function while passing the view in parameters.

If the function returns True, it means the validation is ok, else you add the view to an array. Once you stepped through all the views, you check if the array has some views in it, if so you give focus to the first one and you display an error message to all the views that failed the validation.