# How do I validate user input with Guava on Android?

Tags: java, android, validation, guava, android-guava

In my Android app I have certain forms which I use to get user input.

I need to validate these inputs to check certain conditions like:

- is empty
- is a number
- ...

**How do I validate user inputs using google guava?**

Comment: You mean you would like to have something that let you build a special rule set in "functional" style returning an error check status if any invalid input occurred?

Comment: Yes that is what I need.

Comment: Well, this is definitely out of Guava scope. There are Android solutions that might satisfy your needs being pretty declarative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613321/form-validation-library-for-android . It looks simple and straight-forward. Maybe it would be fine for you?